# Converting polar equation to cartesian coordinates

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I have been trying everything to convert the polar equation $r=\frac{2}{1-\cos(\theta)}$ to cartesian coordinates but I simply didn't manage to know the right answer. Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do some manipulation on your equation.
$$r=\frac{2}{1-\cos(\theta)}$$
$$r-r/cos(\theta)=2$$

Now we can convert with $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $x=r\cos(\theta)$
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x=2$$
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=2+x$$
$$x^2+y^2=x^2+4x+4 $$
$$y^2=4x+4 $$
So we get
$$y=\pm2\sqrt{x+1}$$

Comment: I was able to get to here, but is there anything else I have to do? Because I'm not able to find a final value, not sure if you can find that or not.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply both sides by $1- cos(\theta)$: $r(1- cos(\theta))= r- rcos(\theta)= 2$.  Replace r with $\sqrt{x^2+ y^2}$ and $rcos(\theta)$ by x: $\sqrt{x^2+ y^2}- x= 2$.  Then $\sqrt{x^2+ y^2}= x+ 2$ so that, squaring both sides, $x^2+ y^2= (x+ 2)^2= x^2+ 4x+ 4$.  The $x^2$ terms cancel so $y^2=  4x+ 4$.